# Removing portion of each folder name in Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scripting

I am trying to loop through every folder under "source" and remove the version extension that I've added.

For example,

```
\pathTo\source\FirstComponent.1.5\...
\pathTo\source\SecondComponent.4.6\...
```

Changed to,

```
\pathTo\source\FirstComponent\...
```

Here's what I have so far...

```
SETLOCAL
set "SourceDir=C:\pathTo\source"
FOR /d %%i IN ("%SourceDir%") DO FOR /f "delims=." %%j IN ("%%i") DO REN "%%~i" "%%~j%%~xi"
```

Comment: Remove this `%%~xi` and put an echo before the `REN` so you can see the results first before you commit it.

Comment: Has the version string at end of folder name always 4 characters? Then it would be better to rename the folders by removing those 4 characters at end of folder name in case of last but third character is a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2299431/foxidrive) gave already the right help to find the solution.

```
@echo off
set "SourceDir=C:\pathTo\source"
FOR /d %%i IN ("%SourceDir%\*") DO FOR /f "delims=." %%j IN ("%%i") DO REN "%%~i" "%%~nj"
set SourceDir=
```

`%%~nj` instead of `%%j` is necessary to remove the path to the folder and get only new name of folder without path.

And also possible is following as suggested by [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m):

```
@echo off
set "SourceDir=C:\pathTo\source"
FOR /d %%i IN ("%SourceDir%\*") DO FOR /f "delims=." %%j IN ("%%~ni") DO REN "%%~i" "%%j"
set SourceDir=
```

That is even better in case of one of the parent folders contains also a dot in name.

But if **all** folders have a dot in name like `Component.One` before the version string which must be kept, the following batch code can be used:

```
@echo off
set "SourceDir=C:\pathTo\source"
FOR /d %%i IN ("%SourceDir%\*") DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims=." %%j IN ("%%~ni") DO REN "%%~i" "%%j.%%k"
set SourceDir=
```

And one more solution which removes the last 4 characters from folder name if last but third character is a dot:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\pathTo\source"
FOR /d %%i IN ("%SourceDir%\*") DO (
   set "FolderName=%%~nxi"
   if "!FolderName:~-4,1!"=="." REN "%%~i" "!FolderName:~0,-4!"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Or you could use `~n` at an earlier point instead: `... %%j IN ("%%~ni") DO REN "%%~i" "%%~j"`.

Comment: The problem is that my component name has a "." in it. So the command is clearing past my version number.

Comment: Component.One.3.5 becomes Component

Comment: Well, the batch code (as is) cannot distinguish if a dot belongs to a string which a human interprets as version or is used as separator between two words. You have to define the rules for a different interpretation of dots in folder names.

Comment: Instead of detecting a ".", could I just remove the last four characters off of the end of each folder name in the source folder?

Answer (score 1):

If the folder names that you need to fix are always in this format

```
name.number.number
```

and you need to remove the `.number.number` part, you can also use this method:

```
SETLOCAL
SET "SourceDir=C:\pathTo\source"
FOR /D %%I IN ("%SourceDir%") DO (
  FOR %%J IN ("%%~nI") DO RENAME "%%~I" "%%~nJ"
)
```

Basically, the idea is to treat the version numbers as name extensions. The inner loop uses the `%%~nI` expression to take just the folder name without the extension, i.e. without the last `.number`, and the result is assigned to `%%J`. In a similar fashion, the RENAME command uses `%%~nJ` to get rid of the remaining `.number` (the first one in the original name). And so, using the `FirstComponent.1.5` name as an example, the RENAME command essentially ends up like this:

```
RENAME "...\FirstComponent.1.5" "FirstComponent"
```

Since the method essentially just drops the last two extensions, you can have however big version numbers: `10.123`, `2014.12`... The only limitation to the method is that version numbers must always consist of exactly two parts. (It could additionally support single-part version numbers if your names were not allowed to have a `.`.)